# 500 localStorage is not defined nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] localStorage is not defined                                                                                       ۱۴:۴۲:۵۶
at isAuthenticated (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\CRM\vuenuxi\middleware\auth.global.js:10:17)
at C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\CRM\vuenuxi\middleware\auth.global.js:28:22
at async ViteNodeRunner.directRequest (/C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/CRM/vuenuxi/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:334:5)
at async ViteNodeRunner.cachedRequest (/C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/CRM/vuenuxi/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:190:14)
at async ViteNodeRunner.dependencyRequest (/C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/CRM/vuenuxi/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:224:12)
at async C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\CRM\vuenuxi\virtual:nuxt:C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\CRM\vuenuxi.nuxt\middleware.mjs:2:31
at async ViteNodeRunner.directRequest (/C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/CRM/vuenuxi/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:334:5)
at async ViteNodeRunner.cachedRequest (/C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/CRM/vuenuxi/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:190:14)
at async ViteNodeRunner.dependencyRequest (/C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/CRM/vuenuxi/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:224:12)
at async C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\CRM\vuenuxi\node_modules\nuxt\dist\pages\runtime\plugins\router.js:12:32
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] localStorage is not defined                                                                                       ۱۴:۴۲:۵۶
at isAuthenticated (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\CRM\vuenuxi\middleware\auth.global.js:10:17)

//auth.global.js

```
import { defineNuxtRouteMiddleware, navigateTo } from "nuxt/app";

import axios from "axios";


async function isAuthenticated() {

    let token = localStorage.getItem("token")

    if (!token) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        const res = await axios.get("/user", {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                token: token,
            },
        });
        return res.status === 200;
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}

const isAuth = await isAuthenticated()

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async(to, from) => {


    const isDashboardRoute = /^\/dashboard/.test(to.fullPath);

    if (isDashboardRoute && !isAuth) {
        return navigateTo("/auth/login");
    }

    if (to.fullPath === "/auth/login" && isAuth) {
        return navigateTo("/dashboard");
    }

    if (to.fullPath === "/auth/register" && isAuth) {
        return navigateTo("/dashboard");
    }
});
```

nuxt.congig.js

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config'

export default defineNuxtConfig({


  css: ["~/assets/css/tailwind.css", "~/assets/fontawesome/css/all.css"],

  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },

  modules: [
    "@pinia/nuxt",
    "@nuxt/devtools",
    "nuxt-icon",
  ],
  devtools: {
    // Enable devtools (default: true)
    enabled: true,
    // VS Code Server options
    vscode: {},
    // ...other options
  },

ssr:true,

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) object is under `window`, which only exists on the client side.

I have used [cookie-universal-nuxt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt) in Nuxt 2 to share the cookies between server and client for auth purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As @justanotherpeter mentioned, you can only use localStorage on the client side. Alternatively, you can use cookies for your authentication. Nuxt 3 has [useCookie](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-cookie#usecookie) composable.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76677944/14945696), you can only use the [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) on the client side, but if you are not using SSR features, you can disable it:

```js
// file: nuxt.config.js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...
  ssr: false
});
```

This should solve your problem.